Instances for postively homogeneous function $\varphi$ such that $\{x\colon \varphi(x) \geq 1\}$ is convex
I hope to find some instances for the $\varphi$ given below. A easy one is the linear combiniation $\sum_i k_i t_i$ of $t_i$ ($k_i>0$), besides which I can hardly come up with another one. (The supremum does not satisfies the 3rd axiom.) Any other common examples?


what about $\phi(t) = - |t|$?

What is M? Arbitrary function?

How about $\min_i {a_1t_1 \dots, a_nt_n}$ for positive a’s

@goldboy 1. $M$ is irrelevant to my question. 2. Yes, the minimum is a good example.

Another simple examples include $\varphi(t_1, \ldots, t_n) = t_1 \cdot \ldots \cdot t_n$ and $\varphi(t_1, \ldots, t_n) = \frac{1}{\frac{1}{t_1} + \ldots + \frac{1}{t_n}}$. Yet more examples can be obtained from the existing ones by raising the function to a positive power, i.e. $\psi(t_1, \ldots, t_n) = \varphi(t_1, \ldots t_n)^d$ is good for any $d > 0$ if $\varphi$ is good.
We can also construct a dozen of such functions in an abstract manner. Consider any selector $S \subseteq \mathbb{R}_{>0}^n$ of the family of rays $\{ \mathbb{R}_{>0} \cdot u : u \in \mathbb{R}_{>0}^n \}$ such that $[1, \infty) \cdot S$ is convex. Then we can define $\varphi$ so that $\varphi \equiv 1$ on $S$ and extend the definition to $\mathbb{R}_{>0}^n$ by homogeneity. Explicitly:
$$\varphi(t \cdot s) = t^d$$
for $t > 0$ and $s \in S$, where $d > 0$ is fixed.

I think there maybe  a way to find numerous instances like the following one in the case $n=2$ that can be extended to cases $n>2$. Let $\cal C$ the set of $(t_1,t_2)\in\mathbb (R_+)^2$ such that $(t_1-1)^2+(t_2-1)^2=1$ and put $\varphi(t_1,t_2)=1$ for any $(t_1,t_2)\in\cal C$. Then  for any $\lambda>0$ let $\cal C_\lambda$ the image of $\cal C$ by the homothety with center $O$ and ratio $\lambda$. Each $(t_1,t_2)\in\mathbb (R_+)^2$ such that $t_1t_2\neq 0$ belongs to a single $\cal C_\lambda$, so put then $\varphi(t_1,t_2)=\lambda$. If I'm not wrong you have here an instance for the $\varphi$ of the proposition. You may replace $\cal C$ with any graph of a continuous convex function on $[0;1]$ such that $(1;0)$ and $(0;1)$ belong to it.
